# Which WM_Message to use?

Tags: c#, winapi, postmessage

I am working on a client loader for a game not made by me. I've built a library of mouse and key events to send to the client and they work for the most part. However, there is one bit I cannot seem to figure out.

I made the typing portion of my code this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);

//Send each character of string one at a time
foreach(Char c in Input)
    PostMessage(mainwnd, (uint)WM.CHAR, c, 1);
//Send final enter key to send message in game
PostMessage(mainwnd, (uint)WM.CHAR, 0x0D, 1);
```

This works fine, but there are two things it doesn't account for.

1. In-Game you are required to press the enter key before typing to open chat
2. There are hotkeys to open menus

I have tried things like `PostMessage(mainwnd, (uint)WM.CHAR, 0x0D, 1);` to send the beginning enter key, but the game doesn't process it. Same thing happens if I use PostMessage to try to open menus. Nothing is parsed unless the chat window is already open before sending the message.

I figure I am using the wrong WM_Message, but I cannot find which one I need. I have tried:

1. WM_CHAR
2. WM_SYSCHAR
3. WM_MENUCHAR
4. WM_HOTKEY
5. WM_APPCOMMAND
6. WM_KEYDOWN followed by WM_KEYUP

And maybe a few others, but no luck. Does anyone know which command might work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to get lucky for this to work. Keyboard input is not merely a message. It also affects (among others) [`GetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- and simulating input with these is non-trivial. And if keyboard focus is elsewhere, it can screw things up.

You can try posting [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to generate a slightly lower-level message.

Lower-level still is [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which simulates input from the keyboard driver. Keyboard focus must be in the right place or it will send the input to the wrong window.

Comment: SendInput seems like the best bet, but from looking at the parameters it doesn't take a window handle. The reason I need PostMessage is so I can send data while the screen in minimized. Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but SendInput seems to need the complete focus of the screen.

Comment: You don't understand; "focus" is how keyboard input works. Only one window can receive keyboard input messages at a time: the window with keyboard focus. If you are trying to send keyboard input to a non-focused window, then you are gambling, and in this case it sounds like you lose.

Comment: Another way to explain that... if you can specify a window, you're not doing a good job of simulating keyboard input. The keyboard driver doesn't know anything about window handles.

Comment: The point is if it requires the window to not be minimized then it doesn't fit my needs. SendInput from what I have tested requires you to call `SetForegroundWindow` before it can actually send any input to the client. Although PostMessage doesn't completely suit my needs, it can still send messages with the client minimized. Even if I am currently typing in notepad, the client receives the input from PostMessage. The only problem is, again, certain keys aren't recognized until the client's chat box is open. It's not a matter of losing input, it's a matter of making the client recognize it.

Comment: My point is that you may be out of luck. You are hoping that the app will respond to nonsensical keyboard input (keyboard input messages while it doesn't have focus).

Comment: But it does. I don't think you are getting the entire problem. I can use PostMessage to send any text and the client will accept it, even while minimized, as long as the chat window is open. So it DOES accept input WHILE minimized. In the client, pressing "i" for example opens an inventory screen if the chatbox is NOT up. However, PostMessaging while the chat isn't up does not produce the same result. To call this nonsensical input is just giving up. I'm sure there's a way for PostMessage to work since it already does work for half of it. SendInput is out of the equation.

Comment: You can't just send random `WM_KEYDOWN` messages to an app and expect everything to work correctly. `SendInput` is what you're looking for, you just need to ensure that the app is focused. Either that or a custom Windows message, which you then handle and react however you wish.

Comment: *If* indeed there is a way to get it to work, you won't find the answer on SO, and this question should be closed as "too localized". In this case you need to just debug the target app and figure out why it behaves differently. There is no generalized answer to this extremely narrow situation (app X behaves in Y way under the very specific Z condition).

Answer (score 0):

Try WM_KEYDOWN, followed by WM_KEYUP.  With the VK_ENTER code (I think).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried those too. This was my second guess after Char didn't work. Will add it to the list.